# AttributeError for custom types with mixer

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have stumbled into a pretty interesting bug in klen mixer library for Python.

https://github.com/klen/mixer

This bug occurs whenever you try to setup a model with a column using sqlalchemy.dialect.postgresql.INET. Trying to blend a model with this in will bring the following trace...

```
mixer: ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/main.py", line 612, in blend
return type_mixer.blend(**values)
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/main.py", line 130, in blend
for name, value in defaults.items()
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/main.py", line 130, in <genexpr>
for name, value in defaults.items()
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/mix_types.py", line 220, in gen_value
return type_mixer.gen_field(field)
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/main.py", line 209, in gen_field
return self.gen_value(field.name, field, unique=unique)
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/main.py", line 254, in gen_value
gen = self.get_generator(field, field_name, fake=fake)
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/main.py", line 304, in get_generator
field.scheme, field_name, fake, kwargs=field.params)
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/backend/sqlalchemy.py", line 178, in make_generator
stype, field_name=field_name, fake=fake, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/main.py", line 324, in make_generator
fabric = self.__factory.gen_maker(scheme, field_name, fake)
File "/home/cllamach/PythonProjects/mixer/mixer/factory.py", line 157, in gen_maker
if not func and fcls.__bases__:
AttributeError: Mixer (<class 'tests.test_flask.IpAddressUser'>): 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__bases__'
```

I debugged this error all the way down to a couple of methods in the code, the first method get_generator tries the following...

```
if key not in self.__generators:
        self.__generators[key] = self.make_generator(
            field.scheme, field_name, fake, kwargs=field.params)
```

And heres comes the weird part. Here in this statement field.scheme has a value, specifically a Column object from sqlalchemy, but when is passed down to the make_generetor method is passed as a None. So far i have seen no other piece of code in between these two methods, have debugged with ipdb and others. Have tried calling the method manually with ipdb and still the scheme is passed None.

I know this can be deemed as too particular an issue but i would like to know if someone has encountered this kind of issues before, as this is a first for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixer is choking on an unknown column type. It stores all the ones it knows in [`GenFactory.types`](https://github.com/klen/mixer/blob/develop/mixer/backend/sqlalchemy.py#L30-L42) as a dict and calls `types.get(column_type)`, which of course will return `None` for an unrecognized type. I ran into this because I defined a couple custom SQLAlchemy types with [`sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types).

To solve this problem, You'll have to monkey-patch your types into Mixer's type system. Here's how I did it:

```
def _setup_mixer_with_custom_types():
    from mixer._faker import faker
    from mixer.backend.sqlalchemy import (
        GenFactory,
        mixer,
    )
    from myproject.customcolumntypes import (
        IntegerTimestamp,
        UTCDateTimeTimestamp,
    )

    def arrow_generator():
        return arrow.get(faker.date_time())

    GenFactory.generators[IntegerTimestamp] = arrow_generator
    GenFactory.generators[UTCDateTimeTimestamp] = arrow_generator

    return mixer

mixer = _setup_mixer_with_custom_types()
```

Note that you don't actually have to touch `GenFactory.types` because it's just an intermediary step that Mixer skips if it can find your type directly on `GenFactory.generators`.

In my case, I also had to define a custom generator (to accommodate [Arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/)), but you may not need to. Mixer uses the [fake-factory](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) library to generate fake data, and you can see what they're using by looking at the [`GenFactory.generators`](https://github.com/klen/mixer/blob/develop/mixer/factory.py#L59-L87) dict.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the column type into [`GenFactory.generators`](https://github.com/klen/mixer/blob/ebe40c0d51cee6f956799dbe00e666ab76075c10/mixer/factory.py#L59), which by default only contains some standard types. Instead of monkey-patching, you might subclass `GenFactory` and then specify your own class upon `Mixer` generation.

In this case, we'll customize the already subclassed `GenFactory` and `Mixer` variants from `backend.sqlalchemy`:

```
from mixer.backend.sqlalchemy import Mixer, GenFactory
from customtypes import CustomType    # The column type

def get_mixer():
    class CustomFactory(GenFactory):
        # No need to preserve entries, the parent class attribute is
        # automatically extended through GenFactory's metaclass
        generators = {
            CustomType: lambda: 42    # Or any other function
        }

    return Mixer(factory=CustomFactory)
```

You can use whatever function you like as generator, it just has to return the desired value. Sometimes, directly using something from [faker](https://github.com/klen/mixer/blob/master/mixer/_faker.py) might be enough.

In the same way, you can also customize the other attributes of `GenFactory`, i.e. `fakers` and `types`.